# php split string every

Tags: php, string, ascii, explode

I have a txt file with ascii data which need to be converted into multiple strings. I already converted. Now what i don't know how to do is to cut every 63 times that the ";" appears.

CODE:
This is what i have done. to concert the file to a string

```
$página_inicio = file_get_contents('./file.txt');
```

i tried to use explode to cut but i couldn't do it.

```
print_r(explode(';', $página_inicio, 63));
```

How should i do? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _every 63 times that the `;` appears_? The third argument of `explode` is just a limit on the number of elements that it will create. Could you show some sample input and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Maybe [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is the function you're looking for?

Comment: its a database table which have 63 fields and each field its separated by ";". so i need to divide the big file in N string every 63's ";".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$página_inicio = file_get_contents('./file.txt');
$flat = explode(';', $página_inicio);
$chunked = array_chunk($flat); // Make groups of 63 items
$final = array_map(function($chunk) { return implode(';', $chunk); }, $chunked); // Combine each group back into a string
print_r($final);
```

Comment: Thx, im gonna try it.